# How to pass constructor value in the Flow Shell?

Tags: shell, corda

I tried to start a flow in the Flow Shell.

I have a constructor in the Flow that takes a string and an integer. The string and integer are encapsulated in an object called `Message`.

```
@CordaSerializable
data class Message (val description: String, val id: Integer)
```

The flow looks like this:

```
class Initiator(private val message: Message) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
```

When I enter the following command:

```
start Initiator "descriptor":"A", "id":"12"
```

I get this error:

```
No matching constructor found:
- [message: Message]: missing parameter message
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo. The command used the word `descriptor` instead of `description`.